# Request for the Latest Information on the preferredSingleSignOnMode Property of the servicePrincipals in the Microsoft Graph API's Applications API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, saml

I am seeking the most recent details regarding the specifications of the `preferredSingleSignOnMode` property found within the list of `servicePrincipals` of the Applications API in the Microsoft Graph API.

Question:
Has there been any update to the issue where the `preferredSingleSignOnMode` is set to null in applications configured with SAML but created before early 2020?

Objective:
My goal is to compile a list of applications configured with SAML, anticipating that the `preferredSingleSignOnMode` will not remain null and will instead be populated with a value.

Background Checked:
I reviewed an article last updated on July 14, 2023 (https://jpazureid.github.io/blog/azure-active-directory/get-certificates-secrets-expirydateandtime/), which states that only applications created post-early 2020 (January to March) automatically have a value set for `preferredSingleSignOnMode` when configured with SAML. Consequently, applications created before this period continue to have preferredSingleSignOnMode set to null, even if they are SAML-configured. This makes it challenging to identify and list SAML-configured applications from that period using PowerShell or the Graph API. Although future updates are planned to address this by enabling correct preferredSingleSignOnMode values for older applications similar to newer ones, the timeline for such updates remains uncertain.